# What word characterizes this one statement with its diametrically opposed conclusions?

Tags: synonyms

> "Well we’re getting closer… or farther away."

This was a tongue-in-cheek response characterizing the state of a system.  **What word characterizes this one statement with its *diametrically opposed* conclusions as it's stated that we're either getting [both] closer or farther away?"**  I plan to respond to the person quoted with "I’ve never heard such a ________ statement from you."

Comment: Contradictory. ?

Answer (score 2):

"That's **an oxymoron**", I would say.

> oxymoron - (noun) A rhetorical figure in which incongruous or contradictory terms are combined, as in a deafening silence and a mournful optimist. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oxymoron)

As you are looking for an adjective, you might say "**paradoxical**" or "**self-contradictory**".

Answer (score 0):

It's not an oxymoron, it's not contradictory, and it's not paradoxical.

It simply states that there are two possibilities, one of which is true. And it implicitly excludes a third possibility: that we are staying the same distance away.

If you need a word for what it expresses, the answer is that it is an assertion of a *disjunction*. One (and implicitly only one) of two things (two in this case) is true.

Given the context of someone apparently reporting, with tongue in cheek, the status of a system, another word that comes to mind is *equivocal* or perhaps even *evasive* or *noncommittal*.

Comment: But it is also humorous (because the two possibilities are opposites), which the word disjunction entirely fails to capture.

Comment: It's like John Major's joke about meeting Boris Yeltsin:
"So tell me Boris, in a word, how are things in Russia?"
"Good."
"Well, perhaps in a bit more detail than that...?"
"Not good."

Comment: On its own it is not humorous. No doubt it is humorous in context. But the OP provided no context, beyond saying that it was meant with tongue-in-cheek. If s?he wanted to capture the humor as well, which depends entirely on the context and pronouncing the statement with tongue-in-cheek, then the question should specify that.